# Cloning Input Boxes

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a input box that needs to be cloned up to six times, according to the .clone() function, i can do this, but if the input name has to be changed, how to do this.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
<label for="input">
 <input name="input" id="input" type="text">
</label>

<a href="#" onClick="cloneInput()">Add Another Input</a>
```

So let's say when a new input is created it should add an increment to the name and id, ie: `name="input2"` `id="input2"` and so on, each time the object is cloned.

Anyone have any suggestions on the best/easiest way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Where is the code for `cloneInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove inline event handling use jQuery and instead of using `clone` you can try this.

Markup

```
<div id="inputContianer">
   <label for="input">
     <input name="input" id="input" type="text">
   </label>
</div>

<a class="cloneInput" href="#">Add Another Input</a>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
   var count = 1;
   $('a.cloneInput').click(function(){
       var id = 'input' + (count++);
       $('<label />', { for: id })
       .append($('<input />', { id: id, name: id, type: "text" }))
       .appendTo('#inputContianer');

       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Even if `clone()` is being used this is the right approach. I was in the process of [typing up](http://jsbin.com/atomid/2) something similar on jsbin.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cloneInput` function you can assign values to attributes to the elements like so:

```
$('input').last().attr('name', 'a_new_name');
```

This example would find your last input field an assign it a new name. The same works for ids, values etc. Look it up: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Or as James pointed out, it works directly after clone() too:

```
$('#clone_me').clone().attr('id', 'im_the_clone');
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to use `last`, simply chain it along with the `.clone()`, no need to search the DOM when you already have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work like this :

```
<script>
    var c = 1;
    function cloneInput() {
        $('#input')
              .clone()
              .attr('id', 'input'+c)
              .attr('name', 'input'+c)
              .appendTo('#clones')
              .wrap('<label for="input'+c+'"/>');
        c++;
    }
</script>

<label for="input">
 <input name="input" id="input" type="text">
</label>

<a href="#" onClick="cloneInput()">Add Another Input</a>

<div id="clones"></div>
```